# How can a string can be reversed using the stack?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

How can a string or char array be reversed using the stack?

Comment: What operations does a stack support?

Comment: This is very vague, show us your progress.

Comment: not only is this obviously a homework question, but the answer is about the most obvious thing you could do with a string and a stack. try thinking a little bit next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the entire string into a stack. Then pop it out. Remember, a stack is LIFO, so it works

Answer (score 6):

Push the whole string onto the stack, one element at a time.  Then pop the whole string off of the stack, one element at a time.  The string is now reversed.

Comment: While I disagree with the ethics of giving an answer to what is probably a cheater, yours is very concise and clear.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I had the same dilemma, but I figured that someone was bound to answer eventually, so I'd might as well make it a clear example.

Answer (score 0):

Since a stack is first in, Last out. You take each character and push it on the stack, then pop of each character.

For Example the Word Testing, would push on g,n,i,t,e,s,t and pop off to form gnitest

Answer (score 0):

Just push all the characters onto the stack from char[0] to char[n] and then pop them off the stack back in the opposite order char[0]=pop() to char[n]=pop()

Answer (score 0):

Stacks are LIFO (Last In First Out).

So when you push the characters of the string "Hello!" one by one onto your stack then pop them one by one, you will end up with "!olleH".